# Bash script exits with no error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar, strace

I have a bash script that I'm running from DVD. This script copies multi-volume tar files from DVD to the local machine. Part-way through the copy, the script prompts the user to insert a second DVD, at which point the remaining files are copied. The script exists on the first DVD but not on the second.

This script is simply stopping after the last file is copied, but prior to starting the tar multi-volume extract operation and subsequent processing. There are no errors or messages reported. I've tried running bash with '-x' but there's nothing suspicious - not even an exit statement. Even more unfortunate is the fact that this behavior is inconsistent. Sometimes the script will stop, but other times it will continue with no problems.

I have run strace on the script. Following the conclusion of the copy operations, I see this:

```
read(255, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 5007) = 1302
read(255, "", 5007)       = 0
exit_group(0)             = ?
```

I know that bash reads the script file into memory and executes it from there, but is it possible that it's trying to re-read the script file at some point and failing (since it no longer exists)? The tar files are quite large, and it takes approximately 10-15 minutes from the time the script starts to the time the last file is copied (from the second DVD).

Comment: Is there anything in dmesg to suggest you've run out of memory or anything like that? Something I'd be inclined to try is to modify the script to copy itself to local storage, and execute itself from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll check dmesg. I had actually thought about copying the script to /tmp and then re-calling it from there. My only concern is that the parent script was still executed from DVD. Presumably, bash wouldn't try to reread the parent script until the child script has exited (at which point I'm done anyway).

Comment: I was just able to reproduce it. Nothing in dmesg. Interestingly enough, I reproduced it while running "cat /dev/zero > /dev/shm/file" and opening a very large logfile in vi in an effort to use up as much memory as possible (I got down to 32M free!). I'm not sure if these caused it or if I'm just lucky, but it's worth noting.

I'm going to modify the script to copy itself to /tmp and then re-run it from there. Then, I'll re-test. We'll see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you have already found a workaround, so I will just try to uncover what's happening:

`bash` isn't reading the whole script into memory, it's doing buffered reads on it, only as much as necessary each time (presumably that's for code sharing with terminal input). Before any external commands are launched, `bash` seeks to the exact position in the script and continues to read from there after the command finishes. You can see this if you edit the script file while it's running:

```
term1$ cat > test.sh
sleep 8
echo DONE
term1$ bash test.sh
```

While the `sleep` is executing, change the script from another terminal:

```
term2$ cat > test.sh
echo HAHA
```

Observe how `bash` becomes confused when the `sleep` is complete:

```
test.sh: line 2: A: command not found
```

It remembers that the position in the input file was 8 before the `sleep`, so it tries to read from there and is confronted with the last `A` from the overwritten script.

Now to your case. Normally, having a file open from a dvd locks the drive and prohibits disk change. If you nevertheless manage to change the disk, that should definitely involve an umount which should then invalidate the script fd. That's clearly not happening according to your `strace` output, which is a little strange. In any case, `bash` won't be able to read the rest of the script.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. All evidence I can find supports this. So far, my workaround appears to be working. Thanks!

Comment: I will say though, it's quite odd that bash doesn't report any kind of error. You would think they could print a message that the read failed.

Comment: Yeah but your strace shows it didn't fail! That's the strange part... it just returned a bunch of zeroes that bash then ignored and hit EOF.